# Presentviewcontroller behind a view

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I have a view setup where the my main view has a thin draggable view in it's hierarchy that resides at the bottom of the view.
Tapping on a particular button will present a view:

```
let productDetailsViewController: FMProductDetailsViewController = (UIStoryboard(name: "Catalogue", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FMProductDetailsViewController") as? FMProductDetailsViewController)!
productDetailsViewController.selectedProduct = product
productDetailsViewController.delegate = self
productDetailsViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
```

Is it possible to preset the view behind this bottom draggable view without having to manually present it by animating it myself?

Comment: I think you have to move your dragging view in higher window level

Comment: is there no way under the current implementation to do the same?
moving the dragging view to that level will break a lot of the architecture.

Comment: You dont need to actually "move" the whole view including code to that level, just make an uiimageview from that view and use it as a fake copy of the view, it will work also

Comment: The view actually does have quite a bit of functionality behind it